# Running an AppFabric Monitoring Script Without Using a Local Admin

Tags: permissions, appfabric

[According to this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh351453(v=azure.10).aspx) - I must run any AppFabric administration commands as a user w/ administration privileges.

> "The security identity of the person using these Windows PowerShell
>   commands must have administrator privileges on all cache servers in
>   the cache cluster."

However - I have written a script that gets invoked via scheduled task - it checks to see if a host is down and restarts it if needed.  I don't want to give the service account that will be running this task full admin rights on the entire machine, for security reasons.

**My question:** Is there a way to give a domain account permission to execute AppFabric admin commands without being an admin on the node?